# Python - converting a non-English UTF-8-encoded string into a list of characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 encoded string containing both English and non-english characters. I am trying to convert this string to a list of single characters. When I just use list(), some of the non-English letters are cut in the middle. For example:

```
In [200]: s = "abאב"

In [201]: print s
abאב

In [202]: l = list(s)

In [203]: print l
['a', 'b', '\xd7', '\x90', '\xd7', '\x91']

In [204]: print l[2]
�

In [205]: print l[2]+l[3]
א
```

l[2] prints gibberish since the encoding of the letter א is \xd7\x90 and not \xd7. How can I adequately split the string?

Thanks.

Comment: This may be pedantic, but… what is an "English" character? Naïvely assuming "English" only consists of ASCII characters is risqué.

Comment: Specifically this problem is with Hebrew letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using python2:

```
>>> list(s.decode('utf8'))       
[u'a', u'b', u'\u05d0', u'\u05d1']
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you run Python 2.7

If you will work a lot with UTF-8 you should consider running Python 3.
In Python 3 it works as you would expect.

```
print(l)
['a', 'b', 'א', 'ב']
print(l[2])
א
```